# Is it acceptable to close HTML parsing questions as a duplicate of a Canonical?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, canonical

Consider the following example:

> How do I get the attributes of all the `<span>` tags from a string containing HTML markup? I've tried the following solution, but it doesn't work as I want it. How can I do it?
>
> ... some code ...

For the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag, we have this canonical question which is meant to be used as a dupe-question for all the repeated parsing-related questions:

- [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

The question is basically a list of libraries which can be used for parsing HTML (except [this one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3577654/1438393), which shows some examples). The OP's actual question might only be vaguely related to this question. (Now, don't get me wrong. I appreciate the [efforts by Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3577662/1438393) and others on this question.)

Consider the case where a future visitor searches for a similar query and ends up on this question page. They'll see "marked as a duplicate ..." and think "Oh, my answer is only one click away" and clicks on the duplicate question, only to realize it only provides a nudge in the right direction. The actual question isn't still answered.

My question is two-fold:

- Is closing all (not *all*, the ones that are repeatedly asked) the HTML parsing related questions as a duplicate of this one appropriate?
- If not, what's a better alternative? Try to find a specific dupe and then close it with that? Or answer the question so similar questions could be closed in future?

Answer (score 3):

It's not really appropriate in this case. By their very nature, each language will have a different library to handle this.

There's also the situation where a user can't use a library for whatever reason, and still needs to solve their problem with a Regex. Yes, it's a bad idea, but sometimes those are the constraints.

I can see there being one canonical answer for each language, but I wouldn't make all duplicates.   It'd need to be a case-by-case basis where the accepted answer on the canonical question fully meets the needs of the asker and works within their constraints.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question was a bit specific about the PHP tag, though.

Comment: @AmalMurali I have to keep my answer general so that when other people come and see this, they won't be all like, "But you said *X*". My main point still holds: As long as the OP's question is fully answered (and works within the constraints the OP has set out), then it works to mark the question as a duplicate. Otherwise, don't.

Comment: Example questions: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849209/how-to-parse-cdata-html-content-of-xml-using-simplexml), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950489/php-regular-expression-to-parse-html-in-a-specific-way), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683600/parsing-html-to-retrieve-tags) and [many similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%5Bhtml%5D+closed%3Ayes+score%3A..10+parse). Do you think it's appropriate? (considering the examples)